# Unpacking .torrent files in Google Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, bittorrent-sync

I am working through FastAI's Part 1 Lesson 3 which deals with a Kaggle competition [Planet: Understanding the Amazon from Space](https://www.kaggle.com/c/planet-understanding-the-amazon-from-space)

I am trying to get the files of this dataset into Google Collaboratory. However, the training and testing dataset is stored as torrent files in Kaggle with .torrent.zip extension. I have unzipped them and these are the files that I am working with now

```
`
 Kaggle-planet-test-tif.torrent      sample_submission_v2.csv.zip
 Kaggle-planet-test-tif.torrent.zip   test_v2_file_mapping.csv
 Kaggle-planet-train-tif.torrent      train_v2.csv
 Kaggle-planet-train-tif.torrent.zip  train_v2.csv.zip

`
```

My question is how do I get the files that are in the .torrent form and store them in my Google Drive. I have used transmission-cli to try to unpack these files with no luck. If anyone else has tried something similar or has any idea, I would love your help. I am attaching a link to my Colab Notebook so far which is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FQY4hBgW2-hsajJcDUb85xMZ_4vEnDue)